# How to change CSS of shoppy embedded widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed

I'm setting up Shoppy on my website but I don't like the embed style.
Is there a way to change the CSS from my code?

```
<script src="https://shoppy.gg/api/embed.js"></script>
<button data-shoppy-product="PRODUCT ID">Pay</button>
```

Comment: You can just add it to your style sheet

Comment: How? What do I have to insert in my CSS file? Thanks :D

Comment: yes, include you own css file, lets call it theme.css as an example. inside theme.css you target the element you need to customize.

Comment: Ok for example I have embed--header element. The bg color now is #1c2260 and I want to set to #000. When I do .embed--header {background: #000; } nothing change...

Comment: Make sure your css loads after the script. if the element style is applied at runtime, you can overwrite the style programatically

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I am a noobie >:/

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("embed--header")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000";

Comment: It is still not working :( Can you please try to edit it?

Comment: Please provide a snippet, you do not have enough information to give you a concrete solution

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GvVLe8ah

Comment: I dont see an element with the class "embed--header"

Comment: Run the file in the browser, press the pay button and inspect the blue element (Also can you please contact me on Discord to make it easier? twenty#6325)

Comment: I see, the content is rendered in an iframe, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: I don't know how to insert all of that stuff in my html file... can you please help me? Oh and thank you so much for your patience

Answer (score -1):

You have to include your own CSS file and have to overwrite the default CSS. You can overwrite the default CSS by adding a class selector with the default class selector in your CSS file and write your own CSS. For example, if the default CSS is,

```css
.embed--header {
  background: #1c2260;
 }
```

then you can overwrite like this:

```css
.embed--header.changebackground {
  background: #000;
 }
```

Be sure to give the class name as "changebackground" to your element, otherwise nothing change will happen.